# How do I update a column on a table where duplicate records are found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql script that selects duplicate record . i want to convert it to an update statement where it updates are particular column called STATUS in the table with the string "Duplicated"
Dbms is Oracle

```
Select * From (
    select * from VisaNnsMainTable 
    Where TRN_TYPE = '500' OR TRN_TYPE = '2500') A 
inner join ( 
    select ARN,WAN_NUM, ABS(TRN_AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT 
    from VisaNnsMainTable 
    Where TRN_TYPE = '500' OR TRN_TYPE = '2500' 
    group by ARN, WAN_NUM,ABS(TRN_AMOUNT) 
    having count(*) > 1 
) B on A.ARN = B.ARN 
and A.WAN_NUM = B.WAN_NUM 
and ABS(A.TRN_AMOUNT) = B.AMOUNT 
ORDER BY A.WAN_NUM
```

[image]

Please help me review this I think it does what I want ,but I am not sure if i wrote it well

```
UPDATE VisaNnsMainTable
SET EXCEPTION = 'Duplicate'
 where CONCAT(ARN,WAN_NUM,ABS(TRN_AMOUNT)) in   
       ( select CONCAT(ARN,WAN_NUM,ABS(TRN_AMOUNT))
           from VisaNnsMainTable 
          group by CONCAT(ARN,WAN_NUM,ABS(TRN_AMOUNT)) 
         having count(*) > 1 ) AND (TRN_TYPE = '500' OR TRN_TYPE = '2500')
```

Comment: tag your database

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: @jarlh sorry about that , updated as requested

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hi , I have tagged my dbms now

Comment: Use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement